# Huge string to HTML

Tags: android, html, string

I`m trying to get a String from URL and create an objects by Gson. I am getting to string from this url: http://gotachles.co.il/data.php and then I have to convert it to html before sending it to Gson. The problem is that my string is probably too long (1.5 million letters) and the app freeze when calling fromHTML. (tried and it works fine with smaller strings).

TachlesStringGetter:

```
class TachlesStringGetter extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String myJSONString = null;
        try {

            myJSONString = new Scanner(new URL(
                    "http://gotachles.co.il/data.php").openStream(), "UTF-8")
                    .useDelimiter("\\A").next();

            Log.i("TACHLESSTRINGGETTER", "got sucessfuly");
            Log.i("TACHLESSTRINGGETTER", "" + myJSONString.length());

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        Log.i("TACHLESSTRINGGETTER", "RETURN");

        return myJSONString;

    }

}
```

The HTML asynctask:

```
public class FromHTML extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    private Spanned spanned;
    private String result;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... html) {

        Log.i("FROMHTML", "STARTING");
        spanned = Html.fromHtml(html[0]);
        result = spanned.toString();

        Log.i("FROMHTML", "Returning");

        return result;
    }

}
```

Calling it like that:

```
public void Jsonnn() {

        // sending to anynctask
        try {
            myJSONString2 = new TachlesStringGetter().execute(myJSONString2)
                    .get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // // from html

            if (myJSONString2 != null) {

                Log.i("WEBVIEWCLASS", "DOING HTML STUFF");

                try {
                    afterHTML = new FromHTML().execute(myJSONString2).get();
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ExecutionException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } finally {

                    Log.i("FINALLY", "STARTING SEOND FINALLY");

                    try {

                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                        JsonObj obj = gson.fromJson(afterHTML, JsonObj.class);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), obj + "", 2000)
                                .show();

                    } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "oops jsno!",
                                1000).show();
                    }

                }

            }// first finnaly
        }// second finnaly

    }
```

Sorry for the shitty code :D

Comment: Have you tried to use StringBuilder instead of String?

Comment: any example of how to do that?

Comment: Check my answer, Max.

Answer (score 0):

StringBuilder consume less memory than using String addition `(str = str1 + str2)`. An example use of a StringBuilder:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append("This is my string");
```

To get your long string from your builder (when you are trying to convert it to Gson object) you can simply call `builder.toString();`

So you should edit your Asynctask class "TachlesStringGetter" which should use a StringBuilder, you should also change other aspects of your code whenever you use something to append to String. The + operator uses public String concat(String str) internally. This method copies the characters of the two strings, so it has memory requirements and runtime complexity proportional to the length of the two strings. StringBuilder works more efficent. Hope this helps!